# How do I use the 32-bit JVM on a 64 bit OS?

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, java, 32-bit, openjdk

I have a 64-bit server with only 1 GiB of RAM (VM at Rackspace). I need to run a few instances of the JVM, and the 64 bit VMs are consuming too much RAM. I can't seem to find anyplace that tells me how to install the 32-bit packages of openjdk. When I run with -d32, I get told:

```
# java -d32 -version
This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

When I run with -client, I still get the server VM:

```
# java -client -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Is it even possible to use the 32-bit client VM on 11.04?

Comment: I managed to use one from a 32bit rootfs on a 64bit system , i guess even the web plugin can use the 32bit jre too ... Regards

Answer (score 4):

You can [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) 32-bit versions of Oracle Java for Linux.

These don't come as Debian packages; download the `.tar.gz` version and unpack it somewhere, and then add the `bin` directory of the JRE to your `PATH`.